# Status: Fail, Out of Gas

Tags: gas, error, nft

Can someone please explain this to me? I tried to mint a NFT. I changed the gas price to low and gas price limit to 32000. It showed me 8 dollars something I minted the NFT. But it shows nothing in my creators page or profile page. And the 8 eth has also been deducted from my wallet. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x515a0c9acfe8605ef051546de9fd348bdfec72e413dc432fea0a56cc5167e084

Answer (score 1):

You changed the gas limit to 32000 which is too low for this function to operate.. the $8 cannot be refunded.

Simple example (1 gas is 1 lego piece)

To build a house you need 150000 lego pieces (just a number I don't really know how much it costs) but you sent in your transaction only 32000 lego pieces, which is not enough. The contract does not know exactly how much it is needed and it will try to build it anyway. At some point, the contract reaches the piece 32000 and "tries to get the piece 32001" which does not exist, and therefore it will fail and you sadly have to pay for the effort.

Summary please don't play with the gas limit, the tools can estimate it (most of the time) better than you. You can only change the gas price, you can see the current gas price at https://ethgasstation.info/. But take care changing the gas price to below the recommendation will make your tx stuck and you have to replace it later and pay more.